# Voice recording : Using Red 5 server with PHP /Java

Tags: java, php, javascript, red5

I have requirement where I have to use RED 5 media server for voice recording which going to embed in web page. So I have installed the RED 5 server which is up and running.
Now I not getting any clue how should I start coding in php (since site is designed in php) and design a voice-recording application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had experience in the past with RED5 and some application as video or sound recorder.

You need to use **Flash or Flex with ActionScript** to connect to RED5 and then record the stream

There are many examples in Red5 in the webapps folder, try to download some .FLA and look inside the code.

**The oflaDemo is a good start** for understand how does it work. There are also example as SimpleRecorder or MessageRecorder (up the version you'd installed)

Here a simple example about ActionScript

```
// create the connection
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/myApp");

// create the stream
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.publish("myStreamName", "record");
```

The result will be an FLV file named **myStreamName.flv** located in your webapp’s streams directory.

Once you develop your Flash application you can embed this `.SWF` in your webpage with `PHP`

On internet there are a lot of examples and open-source as Video or Sound recorder as:

http://code.google.com/p/red5-recorder/

Hope this help you to start

Comment: Many thanks Luka :) , i will try and follow your instructions.

Comment: Glad to help, if you feel this answer can be useful dont forget to accept the answer